# MySQL Select where value = 9 'and' value =3

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select from this table:

```
group_id    user_id
3           3
9           3
3           18
9           18
9           39
7           39
```

the user_id where it has both values 3 and 9:

What I want:

```
group_id    user_id
3              3
9              3
3             18
9             18
```

What I tried:

```
select * from prlg_pp_group_members where group_id IN (3,9);  

group_id    user_id
3           3
9           3
3           18
9           18
9           39
```

Thank you

Comment: Assuming group_d,user_id is UNIQUE/PRIMARY... SELECT user_id FROM ... WHERE group_id IN (3,9) GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;

Comment: Is that even possible? Are you sure you don't need OR instead of AND

Comment: AND doesn't work of course. The title just says what I want to achive. The idea. Or is has the same result as group_id IN (3,9)

Comment: I don't get your logic at all actually... Why `9, 39` should not be listed ?

Comment: Strawberry :) that is exactly what I want ... Thank you

Comment: @Brewal: He didn't explain it well, but he wants to return all rows that have a `user_id` where that `user_id` has at least one row where `group_id` is 3 and at least one row where `group_id` is 9.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Haaa ok... That's what the "and" in the title stands for ! Thanks :]

Answer (score 0):

I will explain my thought process as I go along here:

I first wrote a query that pulled all rows with a group_id of 3 or 9 and grouped them together by group_id and user_id. This made sure there were no duplicate rows (like 3,3 appearing twice.)

That gave us this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE group_id = 9 OR group_id = 3
GROUP BY group_id, user_id;
```

Then, you can group that query by user_id on the condition that the user_id appears twice (that means it has a group_id of 3 and 9 because we've already filtered on those conditions.) In this specific example, (9, 39) won't appear in the final result set because 39 does not occur twice.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM(SELECT *
    FROM myTable
    WHERE group_id = 9 OR group_id = 3
    GROUP BY group_id, user_id
    ) t
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Now here's where preference comes in: this query only returns the user_id value. It does not show the group_id value, but we already know that that value can be both 3 and 9 from the subquery. If you do want that value, you'd have to go back to the original table and filter for 3 or 9 and check that user_id is `IN` the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (group_id = 9 OR group_id = 3)
  AND user_id IN(SELECT user_id
                FROM (SELECT *
                  FROM myTable
                  WHERE group_id = 9 OR group_id = 3
                  GROUP BY group_id, user_id
                ) t
                GROUP BY user_id
                HAVING COUNT(*) = 2);
```